# How to sort knockout nested list?

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, knockout.js, nested

Taking the contacts editor here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/

How can you sort by the phone numbers per se?

I want Home First, Mobile, Office, Fax etc.....

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to sort them when loading the data and mapping into the view model structures.

For example, you could sort the phones for each contact here:

```
self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
    contact.phones.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.type > b.type ? 1 : -1;   
    });

    return { 
        firstName: contact.firstName, 
        lastName: contact.lastName, 
        phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones) 
    };
}));
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/531/

Comment: That is really awesome thanks very much. Also how can I state strings in the search? i.e. a.type = "home". Basically set the sort to custom for whatever I define rather than going alphabetical

Comment: You could create a little map to indicate the priority of each type and then the sort function would subtract the two priorities like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/536/

Answer (score 0):

Extending upon RP's answer:

You can attach an event handler to the `type` input to move a `phone` object whenever the `type` changes. I used a linear search but feel free to implement a binary search.

Modified Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zGKM2/